# Is there a proverb in English of killing people as killing animals?

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

What I mean is killing people regardless of who they are. We kill animals for food and that we almost forget the sense of living. Can I say something like "killing people as the way we kill animals"?

Comment: For what purpose? 'Genocide', cannibalism', 'barbarism', all have slightly different senses, according to motive.

Comment: There's the well-known expression 'The _Dogbertians_ treated the _Elbonians_ like animals' (with other referents, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Slaughter** fits that exactly. 
It normally means "to kill an animal, especially for food", but can also mean "to kill a large number of people", usually indiscriminately.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slaughter

Comment: OP asks for a proverb, but seems to mean a fixed phrase.

Comment: What was the purpose of that edit? Is there a meta post on it?

Comment: Sorry; I added and then removed an asterisk or something so I could retract a downvote. You're too new to downvote for a non-matching but otherwise  reasonable answer.